# Next-Image Relative Paths work, but point to 404 pages when crawled

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, seo, nextjs-image

I'm using `next-image`, all my images are on cloudinary, and the image showing ✅. However, when I analyse my website with `Screaming Frog` or other SEO tools, I get a ton of 404s, since they look for those images *on my domain.*

For example:

**next-image component**

```
<Image
    src={`/blog/${imageSlug}`} <=== relative path to image
    width="800"
    height="800"
/>
```

Next.js takes the relative path and combines it with the images path in the `next.config` file. So we get: `https://res.cloudinary.com/jumbodonuts/image/upload/blog/donut.jpg`

**next.config**

```
images: {
        loader: 'cloudinary',
        path: 'https://res.cloudinary.com/jumbodonuts/image/upload/',
        domains: ['res.cloudinary.com']
    }
```

My images are all showing, so it does work. However, the SEO tools / Google seem to think I have my images on the domain my website is on. **They think the relative path is a relative path on my own domain**: e.g. : `www.jumbodonuts.com/blog/donut.jpg` - this results then in a 404 and is bad for my SEO. One thing to note here is that I am using `nextjs` static site generation feature (`next export`), not sure if this makes a difference.

What can I do here? Am I not using `next-image` correctly?

Comment: If you inspect the `<img>` tags generated in your website source, don't they point to the `cloudinary` URLs?

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure the loader.

Read more about: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/image-optimization#loader

> The next/image component's default loader is not supported when using next export. However, other loader options will work.

Comment: Thanks, but I am configuring it already (see the `next.config.js` I cite above). Also, I am not using the default loader which is not supported in next export. I am using cloudinary.